# How to do streaming from AEM-DAM

Tags: aem, dam

We have an AEM server. One of our DAM users want to put videos in DAM and want stream that video from DAM itself. Is there an API that supports this feature which I can use to create a bundle in AEM so that the bundle will handle streaming. The OTB feature of DAM does not support the streaming functionality as of now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can integrate external streaming video providers like [ooyala](http://www.ooyala.com/) with AEM .
Adobe provides Dynamic media which is a cloud hosted solution and AEM has OTB integration with this service .The details of Dynamic media can be found here in this [link](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/assets/dynamic-media/video.html#Working%20with%20Video%20in%20Dynamic%20Media)